# How to use Universal image Loader for loading resources locally

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I want to know how can i use [nostra13 / Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for displaying Images locally i.e from drawable folder along with the Memorycache. I want to use it with ViewPager.
any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try reading [this question, and it's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/541966/1056359)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To load images from assets and drawables you should take `ExtendedImageDownloader` from example project (this class is not a part of library yet) and also set it to configuration.

**UPD:** Loading local resources (from drawable, assets, content provider) works out of the box since **UIL v1.8.0**.

See [`README`](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/README.md):

```
String imageUri = "assets://image.png"; // from assets
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image; // from drawables (only images, non-9patch)
```

NOTE: Use `drawable://` only if you really need it! Always consider the native way to load drawables — `ImageView.setImageResource(...)` instead of using of `ImageLoader`.

Comment: where is ExtendedImageDownlaoder? I am using 1.8.4 with sources.jar

Comment: Removed. Loading from resources works out of the box since 1.8.0.

Comment: can you please answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041676/unable-to-display-images-into-gridview-using-universal-image-loader)??

Comment: Please check this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034576/images-not-loading-from-assets-folder-using-universal-image-loader

Comment: @NOSTRA can use gif image for default image on univeral image loader ..I try with  Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.load1).asGif().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).crossFade().into(imgaeview); if not support  how we can do it. please help us sir.

Comment: No GIF support. Won't be.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever More than one image load from resource ***dynamically (@runtime)*** than prefer these one:

```
String imgUri = "drawable://" + getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
```

Here, **imgName** = Name of image in resource