# display local drawable with universal image loader

Tags: null, drawable, universal-image-loader

I've a problem with Universal Image Loader (which is very fine), I just want to display a local drawable from local. So I put this URL into my String array:

```
public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[]{ "drawable://" + R.drawable.app_icon }
```

but it doesn't work and I've a null pointer exception..

So how display local drawable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098993/how-to-use-universal-image-loader-for-loading-resources-locally

Comment: this link : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/UniversalImageLoaderExample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/UILApplication.java should help me ? If yes, I don't see where.. please help me; on your example project my example is put on your IMAGES variable but she doesnt display anything ..

Comment: yes I'm doing this in UILApplication.java : ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
.memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024) // 2 Mb
.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
.discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
.imageDownloader(new ExtendedImageDownloader(getApplicationContext()))
.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
.enableLogging() // Not necessary in common
.build();

So..

Comment: Did you try run example project?

Comment: yes, your project doesnt display local pics.

Comment: I don't know why you have such problem. Where do you test it (emulator? what device? Android version?)?

Comment: I just have this prob but I made an other think in order to display a static pics from local. I'm building it in 2.2 version SDK and i'm trying on my phone : Galaxy s3 android 4.1.2

Comment: I have this problem too

Comment: exactly same problem here, did you get any solution ?