# Unable to display images into Gridview using Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android, gridview, universal-image-loader

I am trying to display images from `sdcard` and `drawable` inside `gridview` using the following code.But it doesn't works.It crashes in `Galaxy Note` due to `Memory Error` but displaying wrong images in `emulator`  and also takes alot of time to display them.

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc()
.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
```

**Adapter Class**

```
 public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public GridAdapter(Context ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(ctx));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mImages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mImages.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_image,
                    parent, false);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.gridImage);
            holder.image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    width / 2, width / 2));
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (mImages.get(position).getImageSource().equals("sdcard")) {

            imageLoader.displayImage(mImages.get(position).getImages(),
                    holder.image,options);
        } else {

            String url = "drawable://"
                    + Integer.parseInt(mImages.get(position).getImages());

            imageLoader.displayImage(url, holder.image,options);

        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Update :** I have around 30 images in gridview, at the beginning it just displays first image all over the place and it takes around 1 minute to display all the images correctly.

**Logcat**

```
04-16 21:41:16.522: E/dalvikvm-heap(738): Out of memory on a 1042024-byte allocation.
04-16 21:41:16.565: I/dalvikvm(738): "pool-1-thread-1" prio=4 tid=15 RUNNABLE
04-16 21:41:16.565: I/dalvikvm(738):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4054f720 self=0x279080
04-16 21:41:16.572: I/dalvikvm(738):   | sysTid=762 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=2593208
04-16 21:41:16.591: I/dalvikvm(738):   | schedstat=( 47274229556 127781868212 1951 )
04-16 21:41:16.591: I/dalvikvm(738):   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:~91)
04-16 21:41:16.591: I/dalvikvm(738):   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:216)
04-16 21:41:16.591: I/dalvikvm(738):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCompress(Native Method)
04-16 21:41:16.633: I/dalvikvm(738):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:589)
04-16 21:41:16.642: I/dalvikvm(738):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromDrawable(BaseImageDownloader.java:188)
04-16 21:41:16.642: I/dalvikvm(738):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:92)
04-16 21:41:16.642: I/dalvikvm(738):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:340)
04-16 21:41:16.652: I/dalvikvm(738):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:307)
04-16 21:41:16.652: I/dalvikvm(738):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:249)
04-16 21:41:16.652: I/dalvikvm(738):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:131)
04-16 21:41:16.652: I/dalvikvm(738):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-16 21:41:16.713: I/dalvikvm(738):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-16 21:41:16.713: I/dalvikvm(738):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: "It just crashes" is not really an alternative to a stacktrace.

Comment: But you still have not posted the logcat details

Comment: It only crashes in Note due to Memory error

Comment: Use a Mat Analyer to find memory leak. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. Check the 4th point under the useful info @ https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: why it takes alot of time to display the original images?? @Raghunandan

Comment: @NOSTRA Any idea about this??