# android: Universal Image Loader get drawable from string array

Tags: android, arraylist, android-drawable, universal-image-loader

Mostly I found like this on Internet

```
public static final String[] imageurl = new String[] {
    "http://sample.com/sample1.png",
    "http://sample.com/sample1.png"
};
```

So when loading image we just need to call

```
imageloader.displayImage(imageurl[position], imageView, options);
```

**MY QUESTION**

I have string array inside arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="sample" >
    <item>image1</item>
    <item>image2</item>
    <item>image3</item>
    <item>image4</item>
</string-array>
```

Then I'm trying to read sample string array inside arrays.xml

```
....
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
....

final Resources resources = getResources();
final String packageName = getApplication().getPackageName();
final String[] extras = resources.getStringArray(R.array.sample);
for (String extra : extras) {
    int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
    if (res != 0) {
        list.add(res);
    }
}
```

**HOW TO LOAD IMAGES FROM ARRAYLIST?**

It's like

```
imageloader.displayImage(list.get(position), imageView, options);
```

**OR**

**HOW TO SET STRING[] FROM STRING ARRAY INSIDE ARRAYS.XML?**

I don't want to set it manually like this

```
public static final String[] imageurl = new String[] {
    "drawable://" R.drawable.image1
    "drawable://" R.drawable.image2
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

for drawable array ,you can try this:

```
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;
```

instead of R.drawable.image just pass your array position.

**Example :**

Declare your drawable array :

```
public static final int[] imageurl = new int[] {
 R.drawable.image1,
 R.drawable.image2,
...
```

};

now inside getview() method of Baseadapter :

```
imageloader.displayImage("drawable://"+imageurl(position), imageView, options);
```

Comment: I still don't get what do you mean, could you please explain more or give a sample please

Comment: Another way to  more than one images load from resource dynamically http://stackoverflow.com/a/30724508/4025692